# Alternate three and three rows in a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to set the alternate background color for rows in a table - but the twist is that I don't want every other row to be colored, I want to treat them in blocks of three rows.

So for a table with eight rows I want the first three to be white, then the next three to have a background color, and the last two are back to white again.

How can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) your result set based on the index of the result:

```
$("#table tr").filter(function(idx) {
    return (idx % 6) >= 3
}).addClass('alt');
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/V7aw9/)

Comment: I didn't know about jsfiddle. Looks like a great service.

Answer (score 3):

Jquery each function should do it:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$('#mytable > tr').each(function(index, ctr) {
    var id = Math.floor(index / 3) % 2;
    if(id == 0) {
       // CHANGE TO COLOR 1
    } else {
       // CHANGE TO COLOR 2
    }
});
```

The trick is the integer division by 3 [the Math.floor(index/3)], this will give you group of three you are:

```
rows 0-2 will integer divide to 0 
rows 3-5 will integer divide to 1
rows 6-8 will integer divide to 2
```

Then you can mod it to get every other...

Comment: Simpler: `if (index % 6 > 2) { // add class`

Answer (score 1):

With possibly a slow selector performance, you could also do this:

```
$(":nth-child(6n), :nth-child(6n-1), :nth-child(6n-2)", $("#test"))
    .addClass("alt");
```

And you could even do this entirely with CSS3 (using the `nth-child` selector), provided that your target browsers all support CSS3 (not yet).

Answer (score 1):

If you generated multiple `<tbody>` elements in your code, you could do it very efficiently like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jLJMu/

HTML

```
<table id='mytable'>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

jQuery

```
$('#mytable tbody:nth-child(2n)').addClass('someClass');​
```